# Makefile: deleting intermediate files that don't have a dependency

Tags: makefile

stackies!

Assiduous experimentation and searching have not found any solution to this seemingly-easy question.

In my build, .cc files depend on .proto files.  During the make process, the .proto files are translated into .cc and .h files, which are then collected and built into an executable.

How do I make sure that when I delete a .proto, the corresponding intermediate .cc file is automatically deleted in the make process?  (If it isn't, it gets brought into the next stages of the build and that has caused issues in the past.)

Right now, I simply clean out all the generated .cc/.h files when I delete or rename a .proto - this is correct, but triggers a rebuild of almost the entire system.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Would it suffice if Make deleted the generated files as soon as it was done with them (that is, when had finished building the executable)? And didn't regenerate them until/unless one of the .proto files were newer than the executable?

Comment: Good question - unfortunately, the answer is "Not really."  I often run the program in an IDE (i.e. XCode or Visual Studio 2010) - it needs to have those intermediate .cc files in there.  The make phase is simply pre-preparation for this.

Comment: Interesting... Which version of Make?

Comment: It's GNU Make 3.81.  I could certainly upgrade but this is very close to the tip (which is I believe 3.82).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a rule like `clean`, but less stringent:

```
SOURCES = $(PROTOS:.proto=.cc)

.PHONY: tidy
tidy:
        @rm -f $(filter-out $(SOURCES), $(wildcard *.cc))
```

You could then launch this rule manually, or make it an order-only prerequisite of your executable.

Or you could just put the same command in the rule for your executable, but that's kind of inelegant.

Comment: Oh, this seems very doable.  In fact, my makefile doesn't actually (directly) generate the executable - it calls out to either XCode or (eventually) VisualStudio to do that part of the build, so putting that rule in that spot is actually very neat - "tidy up before moving to the build phase".  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this will error if there is nothing to cleanup: `rm: missing operand`

Comment: @Ten: Good catch, thanks. I'll add `-f`.